# reading binary code of a file...in PHP

Tags: php, binary

How can I read the binary code(to get the 1s and 0s) of a file.

```
$filename = "something.mp3";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

I tried this but it shows some strange characters... I presume that this is the formated binary? I was hoping to get the 1's and 0's instead.

Also I am not looking only `.mp3` files it could be anything .e.g: `.txt` , `.doc` , `.mp4`, `.php`, `.jpg`, `.png` etc....

Comment: How did you examine `$contents` - if it was `echo` or `print` I'd assume they interpret things as characters.

Comment: echo is what i used... does it make a difference?(not a rude question)

Comment: now i have just tested it with print var_dump same result...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Files are stored on the computer in binary form indeed, but the 1s and 0s are stored together in groups of 8 (called bytes). Now, traditionally, each byte may be represented by an ASCII character because of the fact that there are 256 possible values that can be represented in a byte - which happens to coincide with the total number of different ASCII characters available (this was not a coincidence but actually by design).

That being said, what you are getting back from the `fread` function is what you're supposed to get: i.e. the contents of the file.

If you want to *see the `1s an 0s`* you will need to print each byte that your receive into it's [base 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) representation. You can achieve that using a function such as [base_convert](https://www.php.net/base-convert) or by writing your own.

```
$filename = "something.mp3";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$fsize = filesize($filename);
$contents = fread($handle, $fsize);
fclose($handle);

// iterate through each byte in the contents
for($i = 0; $i < $fsize; $i++)
{ 
   // get the current ASCII character representation of the current byte
   $asciiCharacter = $contents[$i];
   // get the base 10 value of the current characer
   $base10value = ord($asciiCharacter);
   // now convert that byte from base 10 to base 2 (i.e 01001010...)
   $base2representation = base_convert($base10value, 10, 2);
   // print the 0s and 1s
   echo($base2representation);
}
```

*NOTE*

If you have a string of 1s and 0s (the base 2 representation of a character) you can convert it back to the character like so:

```
$base2string = '01011010';
$base10value = base_convert($base2string, 2, 10);  // => 132
$ASCIICharacter = chr($base10value);               // => 'Z'
echo($ASCIICharacter);                             // will print Z
```

Comment: ok i got an example from hexadecimal to binary conversion...
how would i convert it from that file to binary using the base_convert

Comment: of course it is. I'm not sure what you're tying to do but keep in mind that you do have the ASCII characters at first

Comment: if i have a file something.php that has "hello" doing the above = "0110100001100101011011000110110001101111"
so how would if i put "0110100001100101011011000110110001101111" how would i get "hello"?..........

I am trying to compress the binary (my own way)...

Comment: please see the note in my response. it shows how to do the conversion but please do some more reading about bit, bytes and the way computers represent data before you attempt to write your own data compression algorithm.. in PHP..

Comment: Hi Miky Dinescu, Is there a way to store in .doc file from the binary code to its original from. I am looking for to store images in .doc file using php.

Comment: Just a small correction: Only first 128 characters are ASCII [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 6):

Here you go, the 1s and the 0s:

```
$filename = "something.mp3";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($contents); $i++) {
    $binary = sprintf("%08d", base_convert(ord($contents[$i]), 10, 2));
    echo $binary . " ";
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: thank you man this is amazing....
could you help me to reverse this back to that strange charcter thing?

Comment: Sure, just replace the complete `for` loop with `echo $contents;`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the PHP function [`decbin`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)?

```
for($i = 0; $i < $fsize; $i++){

      $base10value = ord($contents[$i]);
      echo decbin($base10value);
}
```